# ANTLR4 lexer getTokens() method returns only the <EOF> token

Tags: java, antlr4, lexer

Basically, I have the following code:

```java
assert lexer != null;
CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);commonTokenStream.fill();

List<Token> lst = commonTokenStream.getTokens();
FileWriter f = new FileWriter(output);

            for (Token t : lst) {
                f.write(t.toString());
                System.out.println(t.getText());
            }
f.close();
```

But, the file only gets the `<EOF>` token written to it, am I missing something? I'm certain there's more tokens in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy-paste your code, I cannot reproduce it.

This is the test grammar:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : ANY*? EOF
 ;

ANY
 : .
 ;
```

and Java code:

```java
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString("mu"));
CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
commonTokenStream.fill();

List<Token> lst = commonTokenStream.getTokens();

for (Token t : lst) {
  System.out.println(t.getText());
}
```

produces the following output:

```
m
u
<EOF>
```

Most likely, you already consumed all tokens using an instance of a parser. Do a `lexer.reset();` before you create a `CommonTokenStream`:

```java
lexer.reset();
CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
...
```